# How to disable the animation when changing the transform property of UIView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview

As apple document said:  'transform
Specifies the transform applied to the receiver, relative to the center of its bounds.

> @property(nonatomic) CGAffineTransform transform
>
> Discussion The origin
>   of the transform is the value of the center property, or the layer’s
>   anchorPoint property if it was changed. (Use the layer property to get
>   the underlying Core Animation layer object.) The default value is
>   CGAffineTransformIdentity.
>
> Changes to this property can be animated. Use the
>   beginAnimations:context: class method to begin and the
>   commitAnimations class method to end an animation block. The default
>   is whatever the center value is (or anchor point if changed)'

I don't need the animation ,how to disable the animation when changing the transform property of UIView?

Comment: You don't have to call any animation calls to apply a transform mate. You should just do `view.frame.size = transformValues;`

Answer (score 6):

You can disable the implicit animations this way:

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];
// or if you prefer: [CATransaction setValue:(id)kCFBooleanTrue forKey:kCATransactionDisableActions];
// Your code here for which to disable the implicit animations.
[CATransaction commit];
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CATransaction_class/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 1):

It (should) only animate when you change the transform property inside e.g. `UIView  animateWithDuration:` block.
I.e. disabling animation can be achieved by simply not changing the transform property inside an animation part of your code.

Can you post some code where you get animations that you didn't expect?